# How to set a condition statement on a loop process

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am using Python 3; I have a problem in setting a condition statement over some groups (to consider pixel only when there are more than 5 available data) in a loop and I expect to get a blank pixel whether the condition isn't satisfied.

I tried some 'if' statement, but I am constantly getting a KeyError when the condition isn't maybe satisfied.
I'll show the code:

```py
Xpix = 78
Ypix = 30
row = []
mean_val = []

           for i in range (0,Ypix):

              for j in range (0,Xpix):


                  if(len(data_pixel.groupby(['lin','col']).get_group((i,j))[['gamma']])>=5):


                            means = data_pixel.groupby(['lin','col']).get_group((i,j))[['gamma'].mean()

                   else:
                             means = 0

               row.append(means)

             mean_val = np.array(row).reshape(Ypix, Xpix)
```

I expect a 78 x 30 array to plot with blank pixels and mean pixels.
Here I show the error I got:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "map.py", line 415, in <module>
    proc.process()
  File "map.py", line 215, in process
    if (len(data_pixel.groupby(['lin', 'col']).get_group((i,j))[['gamma']])>=5):
  File "/xxx/yyy/anaconda3/envs/gnss/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 680, in get_group
    raise KeyError(name)
KeyError: (10,41)
```

data_pixel refers to a big dataframe with a lot of data. I would appreciate a lot if anyone could help with this.

Comment: It might be because you don't have all group data ranging from 0 to 78 to 0 to 30. to be precise, check do you have lin, col values as 10, 41

Comment: yep, that's the problem, I have some positions with no data at all. I would like to overcome this situation too

Comment: shorter version is use try block catch KeyError Exception perform else action :)

Comment: ok thanks; I solved it, I tried with the exceptions ;)